# Problems plotting with jQuery when using variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following code fragment that is used to plot a pie chart where $valores contains the values to be presented in the plot. This code works as intended

```
<?php

           ...

$valores = '';
foreach ($dados as $dado){
    $valores .=  "['$dado[estado] - $dado[numero]' , $dado[numero] ],";
}
$valores = substr($valores, 0, -1);


?>
           ...

<script type="text/javascript">

pizzaPlot();

function pizzaPlot(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
          plot2 = jQuery.jqplot('chart2', 
                    [[   <?php  echo $valores; ?>  ]], 
            {
              title: {
                  text: 'Parques Tecnológicos por Estado',
                  show: true,
                  textColor: 'black',
                  fontSize: 26
              },highlighter: {
                    show: true,
                    formatString:'%s', 
                    tooltipLocation:'sw', 
                    useAxesFormatters:false
                },
              seriesDefaults: {
                shadow: false, 
                renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
                rendererOptions: { 
                  startAngle: 180, 
                  sliceMargin: 4, 
                  showDataLabels: true } 
              }, 
              legend: { show:true, location: 'w', tooltipContentEditor:'legenda' }
            }
          );

        });
    }
```

However, when I encapsulate the pie chart plot code inside of a function named pizzaPlot(), the chart is not plotted any more. The code below is a slight change to the previous one, now $valores is passed as a parameter rather than being echoed from inside the script.

```
pizzaPlot("<?php echo $valores; ?> ");

function pizzaPlot(valores){

    alert(valores);
    $(document).ready(function(){
      plot2 = jQuery.jqplot('chart2', 
                [[   valores  ]], 
        {
          title: {
              text: 'Parques Tecnológicos por Estado',
              show: true,
              textColor: 'black',
              fontSize: 26
          },highlighter: {
                show: true,
                formatString:'%s', 
                tooltipLocation:'sw', 
                useAxesFormatters:false
            },
          seriesDefaults: {
            shadow: false, 
            renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
            rendererOptions: { 
              startAngle: 180, 
              sliceMargin: 4, 
              showDataLabels: true } 
          }, 
          legend: { show:true, location: 'w', tooltipContentEditor:'legenda' }
        }
      );
    });
}
```

The the message gotten from alert(valores) is the same as the one gotten from echo $valores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first code you get this `[[value of valores]]`. You inject valores directly in to the code. In your second code you essentially do this: `[["value of valores"]]`. This uses `"value of valores"` as a string.

To solve the problem use this to call the function:

```
pizzaPlot([[<?php echo $valores; ?> ]]);
```

and remove the brackets around valores inside the function.

Comment: This way doesn't work either. Moreover, alert(valores) doesn't pop up inside the pizzaPlot(valores) function

Answer (score 1):

javascript variable valores must be array, not string. Use:

```
valores = valores.split(",");
```

Comment: tried with valores.split(","), but I still cannot see the plot

Comment: try removing brackets, instead of [[valores]] try [valores]